# GitHub actions failing when running tests because Poetry is not installing Pandas package correctly

Tags: python-poetry

This is my `.github/workflows/push.yaml` file:

```
name: Push

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Python 3.10
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: "3.10"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          pip install poetry
          poetry install
          python -m pip install -e .

      - name: Run tests
        run: python -m unittest discover tests

      - name: Check code style
        run: pre-commit run --all-files
```

These are the dependencies declared in the `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
pyyaml = "^6.0"
protobuf = "^4.21.12"
gspread = "^5.7.2"
openpyxl = "^3.1.0"


[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pre-commit = "^3.0.4"

[tool.poetry.group.test.dependencies]
pandas = "^1.5.3"
```

I get the following error in GitHub when I push some code to my repo:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_to_xlsx (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_generic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.9/x64/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.9/x64/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/runner/work/path/to/tests/test_generic.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

When I check the "Install dependencies" step log in GitHub, pandas is supposedly
being installed:

```
• Installing pandas (1.5.3)
```

However, when I add `pip install pandas` to my `Install dependencies` step, all tests are passed:

```
- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
    pip install poetry
    poetry install
    python -m pip install -e .
    pip install pandas
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 26 tests in 0.157s

OK
```

Obviously, I don't want to add `pip install pandas` like that. However, it shows that Poetry is not installing `pandas` correctly. What can I do in order to fix this annoying error?

PS: My `poetry.lock` file has the `pandas` package declared.

Comment: Try: `poetry run python -m unittest discover tests`. This seems like an inactive virtual environment issue. See https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#using-your-virtual-environment.

Comment: [Here is an example Github Actions and pytest run with Poetry and Pandas](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/trade-executor/blob/master/.github/workflows/test-and-build-image.yml#L10) - you can look it up as an example. There are often many confusing things with Github Actions scripting.

Comment: @jessehouwing You're right, I've removed the `github-actions` tag. Thank you.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Thank you for providing a file example. It's indeed confusing at times and a bit tricky to get some things done with it.